# display uiprogressbar in uitable cell for iphone app

Tags: iphone

I want to display uiprogressbar in tabel cell through coding. I don't know how to display it. And also progressbar should update or change when everytime the table is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

All this is very well documented in the reference guides, you should check them out.

- [UIProgressView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [UITableViewDelegate](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html&ei=BhZoT_D4HIbJrQevpeDwBw&usg=AFQjCNGiSQtngRuWloYbZm49Pkwdk1zq6Q)

Answer (score 0):

you can create a UIProgressView dynamically in the tableview delegate method and change its value.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UIProgressView *progressView;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
//CREATING PROGRESS VIEW.
progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc]initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
     [cell.contentView addSubview: progressView];
progressView.tag = 1;

    }
    else{
      progressView = (UIProgressView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    }
//SET PROGRESS TO THE VALUE YOU WANT.
[progressView setProgress:0.5f]; 

    ...
```